# How to run a C# Winform in Azure on a Schedule?

Tags: c#, winforms, azure, schedule, webjob

I wrote a C# Winform application that performs a task without user input and I want to run this program on a schedule (every day at 1 AM, for example). I want to set the program up on Azure so it runs on the cloud.

So far, I've successfully run C# Console applications in Azure Webjobs (a service under Azure Web Apps) and those work fine, but if I try to upload and run a Winform I get the error:

```
[03/03/2016 17:27:12 > 252553: ERR ] Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
[03/03/2016 17:27:12 > 252553: ERR ]    at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IWebBrowser2.Navigate2(Object& URL, Object& flags, Object& targetFrameName, Object& postData, Object& headers)
[03/03/2016 17:27:12 > 252553: ERR ]    at System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.PerformNavigate2(Object& URL, Object& flags, Object& targetFrameName, Object& postData, Object& headers)
[03/03/2016 17:27:12 > 252553: ERR ]    at System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.set_Url(Uri value)
[03/03/2016 17:27:12 > 252553: ERR ]    at WebBrowserTest.Form1.InitializeComponent()
[03/03/2016 17:27:12 > 252553: ERR ]    at WebBrowserTest.Form1..ctor()
[03/03/2016 17:27:12 > 252553: ERR ]    at WebBrowserTest.MainStartup.Main()
[03/03/2016 17:27:12 > 252553: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed
```

in the logs. In the code, the error is specifically on a line like where I try to call webBrowser.Navigate function.

```
Uri uri = new Uri("https://www.website.com");
webBrowser1.Navigate(uri);
```

The URL itself is absolutely correct and it works when I run it on my desktop, but I guess something about changing URLs in a C# Webbrowser doesn't work.

So my question is, what Azure service will let me run a winform on a schedule? And if not Azure, I'll take Amazon or some other service. (I don't want to have my own dedicated physical computer to have to run this program. Thanks.

Comment: Marking your main method with `[STAThread]` attribute might help.

Comment: Just curious why you'd be attempting to open a browser from a Web Job - there's no UI you'd be able to access.

Comment: can you convert your app to be a console app? i don`t think Winform would work

Comment: @DavidMakogon I'm guessing he does some web scraping and needs browser to run JavaScript

Comment: Yes, I need to scrape a website and a console app isn't good enough. I need the flexibility of an actual browser. [STAThread] is already marked as the main method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running a webjob your application is running in a sandbox as [described here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox) where it says amongst other interresting things:

> For the sake of radical attack surface area reduction, the sandbox
>   prevents almost all of the Win32k.sys APIs from being called, which
>   practically means that most of User32/GDI32 system calls are blocked.
>   For most applications this is not an issue since most Azure Web Apps
>   do not require access to Windows UI functionality (they are web
>   applications after all).

So if you want to run an UI application you will have to do it on a VM. A [Cloud Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cloud-services/) would probably be the way to go or just a plain Virtual Machine.

Comment: Hmmmmm I was looking into virtual machines and it isn't really desirable. My company has certain features in Azure that are covered, and virtual machines and cloud services aren't one of them. I guess I'll accept this as an answer since you stated Winforms won't work under webjobs, though.

Comment: So, You are telling me that I can call an http request on a VM and which will trigger my automation task?

Comment: I dont really agree as im running Azure Function V1 with heavy use of XAML/WPF windows.. Just gets messy with STAThread but it does work, and im sure System.Drawing uses GDI